# Can't get a Keras model to overfit

Tags: time-series, overfitting, lstm, keras

(Full disclosure, this is a follow-up to [this question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfJFw.png), which wasn't completely answered on StackOverflow)

The input dataset is a time series of some stock price movement, but it might as well be random. I am trying to configure a Keras neural network to **completely overfit** (i.e. memorize the data). That's obviously just a first step.

```
train_gen = keras.preprocessing.sequence.TimeseriesGenerator(
        x,
        y,
        length=10,
        sampling_rate=1,
        batch_size=1,
        shuffle=False
    )

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(128, input_shape=(10, 1), return_sequences=False))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(
    loss="mse",
    optimizer="rmsprop",
    metrics=[keras.metrics.mean_squared_error]
)

history = model.fit_generator(
    train_gen,
    epochs=100,
    steps_per_epoch=100
)

y_pred = model.predict_generator(gen)
plot_points = 100
epochs = range(1, plot_points + 1)
pred_points = numpy.resize(y_pred[:plot_points], (plot_points,))
target_points = gen.targets[:plot_points]
plt.plot(epochs, pred_points, 'b', label='Predictions')
plt.plot(epochs, target_points, 'r', label='Targets')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I would expect the network would just memorize such a small dataset (it sees just the first 100 data points thanks to `steps_per_epoch=100` if I understand it correctly) and the loss on the training dataset would be pretty much zero. It is not and the vizualization of the results on the **training** set looks like this:

[image: Predictions/targets from the training set]

I may be displaying the results wrong because I don't shift targets compared to predictions (see the [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54298123/1766088) for details). But that doesn't account for the failure to overfit. Once I manage to overfit the model, the shift should be clearly visible in the chart.

Any ideas why the model doesn't overfit? Thanks.

EDIT (Training and validation loss in 100 epochs):

[image: Training and validation loss in 100 epochs]

Comment: Does after 100 epochs loss completely stops decreasing? I guess it doesn't, so what about waiting 10x longer?

Comment: The loss on both training and validation set is all over the place (see my lates edit pleas). Nevertheless, I will try to run it ten times longer.

Comment: If this is loss over time, then the problem is not that your model is unable to overfit, but that it doesn't learn anything at all. I marked it as a duplicate of thread that discusses such problems.